# Delete application folder in Android device

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-3, home-screen-folders

Hi I am using Samsung Galaxy S3. In my device I created a folder in Application menu to have a bunch of related apps.

At a point of time I uninstalled all the apps in that folder. Now I cant delete the folder that I created.

How can I delete a  folder that is created in Application menu?

Comment: Samsung likes to monkey with stuff. Have you tried long-pressing the folder?

Comment: What's you Home Launcher?